# Dynamic export in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, promise

I have two config files for my app: An optional provided config file (`env.json`) and an always existing default config `env_default.json`. The app should use the default config if no optional config is provided.

For this purpose I created the next code:

```js
// config/index.js

import defaultConfig from './env_default.json'

let config = null // Config will be reassigned to one of the config files 

export const importConfigPromise = import("./env.json")
    .then(module => {
        // 'env.json' was found, we should use it
        config = module.default
        console.info('Using provided config file "env.json"')
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // 'env.json' not found, we should use the default config
        config = defaultConfig
        console.info('No config file at "env.json" was provided, using default config file "env_default.json"')
    })

    
export default config
```

Then I get the following error (throws while webpack is running):

```js
// components/component.jsx
import config from './config/index'
console.log(config.CONFIG_PROPERTY) // TypeError: Cannot read property 'CONFIG_PROPERTY' of null
```

Meaning that my modules are using the initial `null` value, instead of the new one after promise resolves.

My React App is **checking that the config is loaded** before the render of the whole app:

```
const App = () => {
    const [configIsReady, setConfigIsReady] = useState(false)
    const onLoadConfig = () => setConfigIsReady(true)
    useEffect(() => {
        importConfigPromise.then(
            onLoadConfig,
            onLoadConfig
        )
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            {configIsReady && <RootComponent />}
        </>
    )
}
```

I need to **access the config synchronously**. The app alreadys access the config and I cannot change all the access to do it asynchronously.

Im using create-react-app with:

- react: ^16.13.1
- react-scripts: 3.4.1

Comment: Dynamic import is async. You can fall back to 'require' to make it sync. Or use dependency injection (React context) to provide a config to nested components. Top level component needs to unwrap import promise, the rest will be able to access it synchronously.

Comment: Does `require` work in browsers? Cant find it at https://caniuse.com/?search=require

Comment: It doesn't but this doesn't matter because React JSX doesn't work either. Since an app supposed to be prebuilt any way, it can use whatever build tool allows. The question doesn't mention your setup, but if you use CRA or other Webpack setup, that's it.